# Can we use WhitespaceTokenizerFactory & StandardToken together to accept only few specific symbols?

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-schema

In my scenario i need to use WhitespaceTokenizerFactory & StandardTokenizerFactory together.
Is there any way to use both of them together?? 
My scenario looks like this : 
1. I used WhitespaceTokenizerFactory to search for words like C# or C++. 
2. But, in this case if I search for **SQL,** (with the comma) then results with only **SQL,** pattern appear. 
Expected result : search query must be considered as **SQL**.

My schema.xml looks as below

```
    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField"  positionIncrementGap="100">

      <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use two different tokenization schemes, you should copy the content into multiple fields with the desired analysis setup.  Solr makes this easy using it's [copyFields](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Copying+Fields).

So you could have fieldTypes defined:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField"  positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" preserveOriginal="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType name="text_standard" class="solr.TextField"  positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer"/>
</fieldType>
```

And then define a copyField such as:

```
<copyField source="myTextField_whitespace" dest="myTextField_standard" />
```

Comment: <field name="FEEDBACK" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/> <br/>
<field name="FEEDBACK2" type="text_standard" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/> <br/>
<copyField source="FEEDBACK" dest="FEEDBACK2"/> <br/>

I have created the copy field and re-indexed, but there is no use I am not able to search for special symbols from the copy field. <br/>

query params: <br/>
"params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*:*",
      "_": "1450672539308",
      "wt": "json",
      "fq": "FEEDBACK2:\"C++\""
    }

Comment: Looks like feedback2 is using standard analysis, so of course it won't match.  You need to use the field appropriate to the use case, or you could always query both fields.

Comment: I need a field which works for both **C++/C#**  and **SQL,** (observe the comma) ........If I use just WhitespaceTokenizerFactory, then indexing is done on spaces and search for **SQL,** results only **SQL,** instead of **SQL**.

Comment: That's why I recommended querying both fields.